# How to get data from multiple sites using executeUserSearchRequest API

Tags: yodlee

I recently signed-up for 30-days Yodlee developer trial.

I am trying to pull the financial data using Yodlee REST APIs. After adding a bank account (for bank B1: site in Yodlee's terminology), I could pull the data using executeUserSearchRequest​ API. However, after that, I added another account (for bank B2), and when I pulled the data, it fetched data ONLY from B2's account and not from B1's account. It seemed like, executeUserSearchRequest​ API is pulling the data from the most recent account.  My goal is to pull the data from all added sites.

Any help would be appreciated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pull the data from all added accounts, you do not need to pass any account id in the API and it will automatically pull all the data from the integrated accounts. So please make sure that you do not pass any value for `transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.itemAccountId.identifier` parameter.

Please refer to the [Yoodle API documentation](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/executeUserSearchRequest) for further details.

Comment: Patrick, thanks for the answer. Since "transactionSearchRequest
.searchFilter.itemAccountId.identifier" field is optional, I am not passing it. Still, I am getting the data only from one account, not all.

Comment: Could you provide us with the JSON result you are getting?